# How can I modify this regex expression to include all 3 of these test strings?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The regular expression:

```
(?<=(?i)["|\']word["|\']: ["|\'])(.*)(?=["|\'])
```

will find the bottom 2 lines below what's in parenthesis but not the top line:

```
word: 'something',
'word': 'something else',
"word": "even more",
```

How I can match that top one? The word doesn't have `'` or `"`. I've tried:

```
(?<=(?i)["|\'|*]word["|\']: ["|\'|*])(.*)(?=["|\'])
```

Comment: Why so many assertions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with multiple assertions to cover all your cases

`r"(?i)(?:(?<=[\"']word[\"']:[ ][\"'])|(?<=(?<![\"'])word:[ ][\"']))(.*)(?=[\"'])"`

https://regex101.com/r/taNp4g/1

Expanded

```
 (?i)
 (?:
      (?<=
           ["'] word ["'] : [ ] ["'] 
      )
   |  (?<=
           (?<! ["'] )
           word  : [ ] ["'] 
      )
 )
 ( .* )                        # (1)
 (?= ["'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
['"]?([^:'"\r\n]+)['"]?:\s*['"]([^'"\r\n]+)['"],
```

or

```
['"]?\bword\b['"]?:\s*['"]([^'"\r\n]+)['"],
```

might simply suffice.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0f9ME/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"['\"]?([^:'\"\r\n]+)['\"]?:\s*['\"]([^'\"\r\n]+)['\"],"
string = """
word: 'something',
'word': 'something else',
"word": "even more",
"""
print(dict(re.findall(expression, string)))
print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
{'word': 'even more'}
[('word', 'something'), ('word', 'something else'), ('word', 'even more')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EkHoC0/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/EkHoC0/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---